# Create Nested Objects for JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'd like to achieve the following JSON result/JS object:

```
{
    "mysex": "female",
    "yoursex": "male",
    "location": {
        "lat": "48",
        "lng": "1"
    },
    "description": "descr2",
    "owner": "zBYnfuu8DXEwMttwZ",
    "nickname": "user",
    "_id": "xcGAkaANcmJP9jQu9"
}
```

I already have a message object which gets all other information besides the location nested object values from a form. That works fine.

```
var message = $('#daform').serializeJSON();
```

I already have the lat and lng values stored as variables 'templat' and 'templng' but I don't know the syntax I need to "push" a nested object in message.

Comment: Why are you using an object for a coordinate pair? Why not just a two element array?

Comment: What does your form look like? Where do you get the location information from? What are you trying to do with this data, send it via ajax? Not enough information

Comment: @Linuxios indeed, array would make more sense, but MongoDB docs website gave both options as valid when I first started the project.. Is it a blocker?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos: No, just a style note.

Comment: @ryan Uhm, I think it's pretty straight-forward. What I'm trying to do with the data doesn't impact much the answer to the question. Neither where I get my location information. I mentioned the lat and lng are already stored in variables, that should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `var message = $('#daform').serializeJSON();` is equivalent to

```
{
    "mysex": "female",
    "yoursex": "male",
    "description": "descr2",
    "owner": "zBYnfuu8DXEwMttwZ",
    "nickname": "user",
    "_id": "xcGAkaANcmJP9jQu9"
}
```

Just add

```
message.location = { 'lat': templat, 'lng': templng };
```